# Truffle configuration file name - is it 'truffle.js' or 'truffle-config.js'?

Tags: truffle, truffle-config

Truffle configuration file is mentioned in several places on the web (GitHub, `truffle` package on npm, `solidity-coverage` package on npm, etc.).

Some refer to it as `'truffle.js`, others refer to it as `truffle-config.js`.

When creating a project with `truffle init`, both files are created.

Which one of them should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: truffle.js was used in earlier versions of truffle i.e. 4 and below. Latest version uses truffle-config.js  see https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#resolving-naming-conflicts-on-windows

Comment: @AshutoshSingh: This question was posted when truffle 4 **was** the latest version.

Comment: I understand, the reason I added this comment because I just copied an example built with older truffle version, and I saw truffle.js file. So anyone in future having this situation might have this question.... Hence just put it here for reference

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On windows systems having `truffle.js` in your main folder may create a conflict when you try to execute `truffle`.

Windows first try for executables in your current directory, and `.js` files are considered executables, then when it tries to execute your configuration file it will fail.

To be compatible with windows you can either rename your configuration file to `truffle-config.js` or execute truffle with `truffle.cmd`.

If you do not care about windows then you can use `truffe.js`.

Answer (score 8):

Just for reference, as of Truffle v5, `truffle-config.js` is now the default (and only file that is created) when initializing a new project. Documentation is available [here](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration).

Comment: Adding a reference link and more explanation can improve your answer

Answer (score 4):

truffle.js

and do add the following to it

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `truffle.js`

---

And from this page of [Truffle docs](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration) my understanding is that:

- Both files are created on initiation because **default configuration
  file name can cause a conflict with the truffle executable**, and so
  you may not be able to run Truffle commands properly on existing
  projects.

Comment: **default configuration file name** - which one of them is that?

Comment: @goodvibration `truffle.js` is default.

Comment: "Your configuration file is called `truffle.js` and is located at the root of your project directory." - First line from the link I provided in the answer.

Comment: Be advised, there is no "default" configuration name, both perform the same function and it is not a cause for concern.

Answer (score 2):

Truffle does not distinguish between truffle.js and truffle-config.js.

So, an easy way to deal with this, as referenced in [Mastering Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/appdx-dev-tools.asciidoc#configuring-truffle), is to simply delete this and use `truffle-config.js` instead.

Comment: `truffle-config.js` works for me. Since the infromation dropped down an useful answer for it "- is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)". I'm using Linux