# Truffle.js file is not created with truffle init command

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-test, truffle-deployment, truffle-compile

I have run the truffle init command successfully with creating the following directories and files such as contracts, migrations, test, and truffle-config.js but the one file is missing as truffle.js? Any solution

Comment: Is it causing any problem?

Comment: Actually, i am following this tutorial (https://medium.com/haloblock/deploy-your-own-smart-contract-with-truffle-and-ganache-cli-beginner-tutorial-c46bce0bd01e)

Comment: When i compile the contract. its shows the following error (Error: CompileError:ParserContract.sol:3:1: ParserError: Expected Pragma, import.....). It seems to be missing of this file or not?

Comment: https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/creating-a-project  as per the official documentation, only your mentioned folder & file will be created.

Comment: See [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/38117/16043) on the difference between truffle.js and truffle-config.js.

Answer (score 1):

With latest truffle versions, when execute truffle init command, only truffle-config.js is created. So, add the configuration details to this file.